# How to refresh a parent page when the child page is closed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a desktop application.

When a child page is closed and the control is returned to the main page, the main page does not refresh.

Does anybody know how to make this work using `C#` Visual Studio?

Comment: This is not a usual behavior of dialogs, please show your code!

Comment: Do you have a method which refresh the main form??

Comment: What should be refreshed? We have no idea what's on your main page, or what you expect to change when you close your child page.

Comment: private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
this.ActiveMdiChild.Close(); //active child form is closed. ?????
imageToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false; 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}

Comment: @reizonshrestha, that should be in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to a function on the event FormClosed in your sub form.

```
    Form subForm = new Form();
    subForm.FormClosed += subForm_FormClosed;
    subForm.ShowDialog();

    private void subForm_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here you can update what you wish.
    }
```

The `subForm_FormClosed` will be called once the `subForm` form has been closed.